# Facebook php-sdk getUser returns 0 with Laravel - It used to work

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-4

i've looked at loads of other answers for the returning 0 issue.

The difference with mine is that it used to work.

Stupidly i made a couple of changes today, firstly updating my AWS server (including php) and then moving my app from a sub-domain to root.

The get login url works, but i just always get 0 from getUser.

I've spent the whole day on it :(

Any ideas?

Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.3)
PHP v 5.5.7
Laravel 4

Comment: What `getUser`, Any code ?

Comment: subdomain hardcoded somewhere or set in the dev settings of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't want to be someone that never posts the resolution.

I think it was an issue with the Curl module.

Ran a yum update on the ec2 server today and it's back up and running perfectly now.

Bit annoying, but hey ho!